# How to mock IDataReader.GetValues()?

Tags: unit-testing, moq

I need to mock a call to IDataReader.GetValues(array) using Moq. The GetValues method should populate "array" with the values from the current row in the DataReader and return the data reader field count.

Here is my Mock setup:

```
var data = new object[] { };

var reader = new Mock<IDataReader>();
reader.Setup(r => r.GetValues(data)).Callback<object[]>(d => {
    Array.Resize(ref d, 2);
    d[0] = "value 1";
    d[1] = "value 2";
}).Returns(2);
```

... and this is the code being tested ("_reader" is the Mock object):

```
public int GetValues(object[] values)
{
    int result = _reader.GetValues(values);
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        // this is not executed because values.Length == 0
    }
    ...
```

In the code above, result == 2 (ok Mock Setup is working) but "values" never gets populated!

How can I setup the Mock object to populate the "values" array?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because `data` is empty in the code above. When you create the `object[]` in the first instance, you will need to populate it or it won't have anything in it when you mock the call to `IDataReader.GetValues`

Comment: Yes I can do that, but I was expecting the code inside "Callback" to resize and populate my empty array.

Comment: The callback is used to verify the contents afterwards rather than populate before. You can pass your expected and the actual into the callback to verify that they both contain the same elements

Answer (score 1):

Can do like this

```
Mock<IDataReader> dataReader = new Mock<IDataReader>();
object[] copyToData = { "value 1", "value 2"};
dataReader.Setup(m => m.FieldCount).Returns(copyToData.Length);
dataReader.Setup(m => m.GetName(0)).Returns("Column1");
dataReader.Setup(m => m.GetFieldType(0)).Returns(typeof(string));

dataReader.Setup(m => m.GetName(1)).Returns("Column2");
dataReader.Setup(m => m.GetFieldType(1)).Returns(typeof(string));

dataReader.Setup(m => m.GetValues(It.IsAny<object[]>()))
    .Callback(new Action<object[]>(d =>
    {
        Array.Copy(copyToData, 0, d, 0, d.Length);
    }))
    .Returns(() => copyToData.Length);

dataReader.SetupSequence(m => m.Read())
    .Returns(true)
    .Returns(false);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).